# analyze project in eclipse with sonarqube

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

i want use sonarqube for analyze a simple java project in eclipse.

```
public class AAA {
String kkk="";  
}
```

this is test for a simple project analyzing
  but after analyze project in eclipse by sonarqube ,i get error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/db?project=aaaaa]. Response code: 500
at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:281)
at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:235)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:116)
at com.google.common.io.Files.copy(Files.java:231)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.download(ServerClient.java:69)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.downloadDatabase(PreviewDatabase.java:101)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.start(PreviewDatabase.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you didn't link your project to one analyzed on a SonarQube server . See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse#ConfiguringSonarQubeinEclipse-LinkingaProjecttoOneAnalyzedonaSonarQubeServer